# How to use public IPs from remote network in my local network

Tags: linux-networking, tunneling

[The image shows the current remote setup and proposed local network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOYBR.jpg)

I have 2 networks at different locations. For your better understanding one network I named remote network and another is local network. Both network have 1 linux box (CentOS 6.10) each.
Remote Network scenario:
The remote Linux have Public IP on its eth0 (IP 202.52.151.58, Subnet 255.255.255.224, GW 202.52.151.58). The Linux box connected to a Router(IP 202.52.151.62). The router have 202.52.151.32/27 IP Block aasigned.

Local Network scenario:
The Local Linux eth0 is connected to the internet router with private IP 192.168.1.127. The Linux eth1 is connected to 2 Hosts (1 Windows PC and 1 Voip Gateway) through a Switch. I want to assign the remote network's Public IP for the the hosts at the local network.

Please help me to do so.

Comment: Use a VPN......

Answer (score 2):

Implement IPv6. Give each site a generous allocation, in an address plan that fits your organization. At least a /56, which is a couple hundred /64 subnets. Every device gets public IPs.

Yes, you will still have to maintain IPv4 for things. And there are ways design this with v4.  But why share a meager count of IP addresses and deal with NAT, when you can connect everything via the v6 internet?

Comment: hi John, I don’t have ipv6 at this moment. NAT will not solve my issues. So please advise me how I can solve my required issue.

Comment: IPv6 is my answer. Ask your ISP for it. Stealing IP address space from another site becomes obsolete when every net can get their own.